# need photo_reference from google places api

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm using the api of google places to get photos but I got a problem. Here it is:

So I'm using the api from google places. And i get the results of a place. But here is the code where I keep the results:

```
 @Key
public String id;

@Key
public String name;

@Key
public String reference;

@Key
public String icon;

@Key
public String vicinity;

@Key
public String website;
```

Now the results I get back from google are this:

```
"icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id" : "4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
      "name" : "Google Sydney",
      "photos" : [
         {
            "height" : 1536,
            "html_attributions" : [ "Van Google-gebruiker" ],
            "photo_reference" : "CoQBdQAAAPga2KHTGQ7bwXYWqWdcjk3ysuclkMPLwteQJQKCLDTNSIW3r3UXXph7Xvd1xDglxSo4Tj_kQ7PtbmEp7nFbXs8-_TgX15Uw3yvjSs6InXSypn9RXEG46sjFZ1jnIK53_mGtwPf9X2IAUriXYsBaSq-eQ5y5QN6XuzjxoAPm-MBjEhD6ijhkCpZni0RmQthFsmBaGhSFdmnUCWAm_yacKUUWCRvP1Ci7Sg",
            "width" : 2048
         },
         {
            "height" : 480,
            "html_attributions" : [ "Van Google-gebruiker" ],
            "photo_reference" : "CnRqAAAAP3g4h5maCy8vR4D--VmH_LCCdoo07fGP9nsi0EvYF_U9dsdmGf_pLNl71drFGkAi4DOHkyv1SD66iaRUL7C-C8Ywjh1I5Z5zexGdzmVV4ST9FKrPRQzW3nalzEF4cf2hJYPKD_QjcW9a-4mhR1eaihIQpipj9088MwpwIDEUiQ85PRoUENmOYDyfcp2INEjovgLgUVVx7k8",
            "width" : 640
         }
      ],
```

Now I only need the photo_reference. How can I do that? Because it's in a array? I only need the first photo_reference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: see [this](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) doc after retrieving photo_reference from json as string you will need to use [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CoQBegAAAFg5U0y-iQEtUVMfqw4KpXYe60QwJC-wl59NZlcaxSQZNgAhGrjmUKD2NkXatfQF1QRap-PQCx3kMfsKQCcxtkZqQ&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere) API to get photo from google place api

Answer (score 0):

Use this url on your code with your key and your photo_reference:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=70&photoreference=CoQBdQAAAPga2KHTGQ7bwXYWqWdcjk3ysuclkMPLwteQJQKCLDTNSIW3r3UXXph7Xvd1xDglxSo4Tj_kQ7PtbmEp7nFbXs8-_TgX15Uw3yvjSs6InXSypn9RXEG46sjFZ1jnIK53_mGtwPf9X2IAUriXYsBaSq-eQ5y5QN6XuzjxoAPm-MBjEhD6ijhkCpZni0RmQthFsmBaGhSFdmnUCWAm_yacKUUWCRvP1Ci7Sg&sensor=true&key=YOURKEYHERE
```

Remember: the param maxwidth can be set until the limit on picture over your response param: "height" : 480